# Adding Organisations Dynamically

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In hyperledger fabric 1.0, is it possible to add new organisations after network bootup? I mean after creating the orderer block can be add new organisations to the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-questions

> 1) In the 1.0.0-alpha, you could add organizations by adding new
>   channels but it was not possible to add new organizations to existing
>   channels
>
> 2) In the current master / upcoming alpha2 release, it is technically
>   possible to change the membership for an existing channel as well as
>   add/remove members from the consortium. You can do this via config
>   update transactions. While there is support for this within the
>   ordering service, there is currently no support for this in the
>   tooling but work is underway to produce a tool to aid in reconfiguring
>   channels

[Direct link](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-questions?msg=diRMfM3xJgZR6kT2x)